# Prononciation de « des amis » et « deux amis »

Tags: prononciation, voyelles, liaisons

Pour un étranger, « des amis » et « deux amis » sont identiques avec la liaison. Est-ce que les français (ou autres locuteurs natifs) peuvent les distinguer ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La prononciation n'est pas la même pour le premier *de-*.

Le *e* de *Des amis* sonne comme dans *mes*, *tes* ou *ces* ; dans certaines régions la voyelle est [`/e/`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) (comme dans *pré*), dans d'autres c'est [`/ɛ/`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) (comme dans *mère*).

Celui de *Deux amis* par contre est plus comme celui de *peu* ou *creux* [`/ø/`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_rounded_vowel). C'est une sonorité plus arrondie.

La différence est suffisante pour qu'il n'y ait pas d’ambiguïté entre les deux.

On pourra se reporter au [schéma audio des voyelles françaises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio).

---

Si j'ai mal compris la question et qu'elle portait sur une différence de prononciation de la liaison elle-même, il n'y en a pas. Mis à part le premier *de-*, la suite de ces expressions est identique à l'oreille.

Answer (score 6):

Le son de la première voyelle est clairement distincte.  Le guide [suivant](http://post.queensu.ca/~lessardg/Cours/215/chap2.html#2.5) pourrait vous aider à pratiquer.  La première est (d'après les symboles [API](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_phon%C3%A9tique_international)) [e] et la deuxième une [ø].  Comme vous, je suis en train d'apprendre la langue et j'ai trouvé que ça vallait la peine d'apprendre les symboles API.